# Javascript function not triggering in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I know that others have had similar problems, but none of the answers applied to the problem which I am having....

This script is working fine in safari and firefox, but not at all in chrome.... any ideas why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id){
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var divid = document.getElementById(id);
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
            for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
                divs[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            divid.style.display = "block";
        } 
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no jQuery in your code. change your tag to java-script

Comment: What is returning `if (document.getElementById) {`?

Comment: this should return false if document.getElementById is undefined which is unlikely and true if there is such function.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/L3weh39L/

Comment: could you make a fiddle that's not working??

Comment: Sorry, yes I did not give enough code/details here... the hidden window should ease in (opacity) with jquery. THIS is what does not work in chrome: 

`<a href="#><div class="new-window-show">SHOW NEW WINDOW</div></a>

<script> 

$( ".new-window-show" ).on( "click", function() {
     $( "#home, #photos").fadeOut(1200);
     $( "#new-window" ).fadeIn(1200);                    return false;
         } 

</script>`

Comment: Ooof, that edit is a big mess, sorry about that.

Comment: Well, somehow this problem sorted itself out... sorry that I wasted your time, and thanks for helping.